Testing a vercel preview app using cypress
How can I dynamically retrieve the URL of a preview app created on Vercel when a pull request is made in a Next.js project deployed via GitHub? I want to utilize Cypress for testing purposes on this deployed app, but I'm unsure how to automatically obtain the preview app's URL for visiting it in Cypress tests.
describe("template spec", () => {
  it("passes", () => {
    cy.visit("url");
    cy.get(
      'img[alt="Next.js Logo"][fetchpriority="high"][width="180"][height="37"][decoding="async"][data-nimg="1"][class="relative dark:drop-shadow-[0_0_0.3rem_#ffffff70] dark:invert"]'
    ).should("exist");
  });
});


Gleb Bahmutov has done this, see Test the Preview Vercel Deploys.
It's worth reading right through, but the bottom line is you can grab the URL of the preview from a github action event, setting it to the CYPRESS_BASE_URL environment variable.
Ref Cypress - Overriding Configuration

The basic github action

.github/workflows/ci.yml
name: ci
# https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows
on: [deployment_status]
jobs:
  e2e:
    # only runs this job on successful deploy
    if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Run Cypress 
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        env:
          CYPRESS_BASE_URL: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.target_url }}


I was able to follow through the resources that you shared and made a great step. However I am still facing an issue when the test runs on github actions.
I get Error: Could not find Cypress test run results.

Solved this by adding  with:                   record: false                   config-file: cypress.config.ts # Update to the new configuration file under steps
